# IE - innerHtml Error Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

So I have a javascript function that runs a java applet.

```
var d=document;
i = d.createElement("object");
  i.setAttribute("codetype","application/x-java-applet");
   i.setAttribute("type","application/x-java-applet");
 i.setAttribute("code","myclass.class");
 i.setAttribute("archive","myapp.jar");
  i.setAttribute("cache_archive","myapp.jar");
 i.setAttribute("height","1");
 i.setAttribute("width","1");
 i.setAttribute("id","cv1");
 i.setAttribute("MAYSCRIPT","true");
 i.innerHTML = '<param name="a" value= "' + a + '" /><param name="b" value= "' + b + '" /><param name="c" value="c"/><param name="d" value="' + d + '"/>';
 d.body.appendChild(i);
```

The problem is that IE gives an unknown error at the line 'i.innerHTML...'. I've tried searching on how to fix this problem, however all the answers are related to tables and cells. Can someone please tell me how to modify my code so the code is compatible with IE.

Comment: In that case, your variable "a", "b" and "d" are not defined

Comment: just examples. ie said the error was at the line where innerHTML starts

Comment: well... d is defined and a newly created DOM node ;)

Comment: yea a,b and c are defined before this snippet

Comment: Yes, but `d` is overwritten with your `object` node, at least in the code you provided.

Comment: @user2009694 can you please provide the exact error you are getting and the version of IE.

Comment: sorry, the d in the params is just an example, different to the real d. the error i am having is "unknown error" and i am using IE8

Comment: So if we replace a,b,d in the innerHTML-line with k,l,m you get the same error? Did you try switching the last two lines?

Answer (score 0):

In this code :

```
i.innerHTML = '<param name="a" value= "' + a + '" /><param name="b" value= "' + b + '" /><param name="c" value="c"/><param name="d" value="' + d + '"/>';
```

What is a,b,c ? Have you declared it ?

Comment: yes, they are just examples. the real error begins at the innerHTML line

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `b` are not defined, and you are trying to add the created `object` element (`d`) as a string value into the last `param`. I also suggest to put a `var` before the first `i`, to not confuse it with DOM elements or other variables.

Comment: yes, they are just examples. the real error begins at the innerHTML line

Comment: Maybe you should also try to do `d.body.appendChild(i)` before the `innerHTML` call, with your real code